# Would a tips and tricks section be welcome on the site?

Tags: discussion, questions

Sorry that this is not a question, and perhaps being posted in the wrong area.

I was thinking that it would be great if instead of a questions column we could have a tips n tricks column where we could post things we find on ways to do things on the Android.

This could alleviate some of the questions asked if someone else has already posted a better or different method of doing the thing they are having an issue with.

Then as we discover great features we can hop on and post about them so everyone can benefit. Would also change the feel of the site as only having problems posted makes it look like Androids are nothing but trouble!

Comment: This web site is specifically a questions and answers site. Please see this question for some places that do carry Android related tips and tricks http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4060/blogs-for-android-apps-and-tips

Comment: You can make a question out of the tips and tricks you want to talk about, and answer it yourself (Jeopardy-style question is specifically allowed in StackExchange). I've done several such questions in the past.

Answer (score 6):

As others have noted, there are other forums out there that would probably be more appropriate.

That said, if you had a problem that you fixed yourself, there's no reason you couldn't post the problem as a question and then answer it with your solution. Other people might find it useful and you may find that there was alternative (and perhaps better) solution.